# ng-switch is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Here is the script:

```
<script src="angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller("myController", function ($scope) {
        $scope.names = [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: 'Michael',
            age: 12
        }
    ];
});
</script>
```

and the body of my html:

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
    <div ng-switch on="{{names[0].id}}">
        <div ng-switch-when="1"><img src="/images/id1.jpg"></div>
        <div ng-switch-when="2"><img src="/images/id2.jpg"></div>
   </div>
</body>
```

What I would like to do is that when id is 1, it will display id1.jpg and when 2, id2.jpg...but this is not working

Can you suggest other ways to accomplish this?

Comment: Try removing `{{}}` from `on`

Answer (score 0):

The problem was resolved  by way of [CodeHater's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18871568/ng-switch-is-not-working#comment27849118_18871568); the OP changed the Angular expression the `ng-switch on="{{names[0].id}}"` to a regular Javascript expression by removing the double brackets.  The resulting code was `ng-switch on="names[0].id"`.